# Matching Python Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like...

```
dict1 = {'England':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'Canada':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]...etc}
```

I also have another dictionary that looks like...

```
dict2 = {'England':15,'Canada':10...etc}
```

Im trying to do a match for the key and then append the value to dict1 so I can get something like

```
dict3 = {'England':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15],'Canada':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10]...etc}
```

so far I believe I will have to use the setdefault append method.  However Im not quite sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to see if the key from dict1 is in the key set of dict2, and then append it....

There might be something more pythonic, but this is straightforward...

```
for key in dict1.keys():
  if key in dict2.keys():
    dict1[key].append(dict2[key])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dict1 = {'England': range(1, 8), 'Canada': range(1, 8)}
dict2 = {'England': 15, 'Canada': 10, 'France': 5}
for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict1.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Result:

```
{
    'Canada': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10], 
    'England': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15],
    'France': [5]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dict comprehension:

```
dict3 = {k:v+[dict2[k]] for k,v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
```

Results in:

```
{'England': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15], 'Canada': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10]}
```

I assume both dicts have matching keys, as you have not specified if some keys may not exist in dict2 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
print {k: v+[dict2[k]] for k,v in dict1.items()}
```